# Java regex for code, such as 'this.'?

Tags: java, regex

How do I search through source code to find and remove all uses of 'this' for example:
'this.getVersion()' would change into 'getVersion()'

I figure I need a regex, but I don't know how to create one to search the code for it.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to try something on your own first. If what you try doesn't work, come back and tell us what you did and what went wrong. Also, this activity is ill advised for reasons mentioned in answers.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to remove .this, there is no performance loss, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would advice against that. Because say you have a method

```
public class Foo {

    private int a;

    public void Bar (int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }


}
```

By removing `this.`, the semantics of the method are altered.

You cannot modify this semantic-safe without building a parse-tree and doing some semantical analysis.

---

If you really wish to proceed:

```
\bthis\.
```

Is a regex that will probably do the trick.

Comment: I know in cases like this, and when I said this, I mean to search for any word, not just 'this'

Comment: But you can never be sure, except when you for instance first built a tree using the context free grammar of Java and then perform some semantical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

A regex could work, to match words containing "this" (say, `(.*)(this)(.*)`)

But without more semantic information, you could be removing random this's. Ever worse, you might change the meaning of the code. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to write this in Java, and that you have read the cautionary note in the other answer. You can just load each file into a String and use

```
myFileString.replaceAll("\\bthis\\.", "");
```

See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for details.